# running a binary with several added parameters works from bash shell , but not if the parameters are packaged in a variable

Tags: command-line, bash

In my particular case the binary is 'asterisk', but I tested other scenarios with different binaries (e.g 'fs_cli') and the result is the same.
In a nutshell if I execute :

```
asterisk -rx 'core show version'
```

that works fine and produces the expected result (returns the version). However if I try something like this :

```
var='core show version';asterisk -rx $var
```

It fails. I tested many different variations for the var like:

```
var="'core show version'"
var="\'core show version\'"
var='"core show version"'
```

and some more, but it always fails. During my tests it has become obvious, that the result is like as I give the binary only the first of the parameters. In different words the result will be the same if I execute:

```
asterisk -rx core
```

or

```
asterisk -rx core show version # with no quotes
```

The binary expects 1 and only one parameter after the '-rx '. If you need to pass more, you put them in "" or '', so they are passed as one. But I can't make that work with a variable. It looks like when I use a variable, for some reason the shell removes the quotes alwais and passes the string like severals parameters instead of one. Hopefully there is a solution and someone will help me with it?
There are several use cases for using such syntax, but I don't want to overcomplicate the question with such details. In short: I'd like to use it from a script with human input.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the *definition* that needs quoting, it's the variable *expansion*:
Instead of:

```
var='core show version';asterisk -rx $var
```

like this:

```
var='core show version';asterisk -rx "$var"
```

See:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)